# Pass data table to oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

I need to pass search criteria as data table to stored procedure in oracle, and return data table to display it as a report.

So the user will enter list of reference numbers and list of customer names, and the application will display all the details of that reference numbers and customer names as report.

I'm gonna use crystal report and c#

My problem here in stored procedure, how can I pass the data table and build the query based on it ?

Comment: An Oracle database cannot read a .Net DataTable.

Comment: I know that, I thought to pass it as array, array of reference numbers and array of customer names

Comment: If you only need a list of reference numbers and customer names, could you convert them to a pair of comma-separated strings and pass them to the procedure, which can then be used for an IN clause in the query? (Not sure if this is a bad design though)

Comment: you need to create a stored procedure declaring the variables and assigning them = null, then in your Select statement utilize the `ISNULL` function..this is actually quite simple

Comment: @MethodMan - there is no ISNULL function in oracle.  Maybe NVL()?

Comment: Maybe this -http://appsjack.blogspot.com/2010/09/pass-custom-udt-types-to-oracle-stored.html

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following approach:

```
create or replace type strtable as table of varchar2(500);
/

create or replace function my_func(a in strtable)
return varchar2 /* OR strtable OR something else */
as
begin
    ...
end;
/


select my_func( cast( multiset( SELECT ... FROM TABLE WHERE ... ) as strtable ) ) from dual;
```

Also you may want to read Oracle documentation about MULTISET, CAST, LISTAGG